# Onde deve ficar os módulos do programa?

Tags: python, import, módulo-python

Eu desenvolvi um de agenda pessoal em **Python** usando o **Sqlalchemy** e o **PyQt5**. Eu percebi que, por exemplo:

Eu tenho o aquivo main.py

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

login = TelaLogin()

if login.exec() == 1:
    sessao_user = login.retorna_sessao()
    janela_principal = JanelaPrincipal(sessao_user)
    janela_principal.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

e o arquivo add_user.py:

```
 import sqlalchemy
 user = Usuario(usuario_nome = name, usuario_login = login, usuario_senha = password)
 connection.session.add(user)
 connection.session.commit()
```

Então eu percebi que, se eu mudar o **import sqlalchemy** para o arquivo **main.py** não muda o comportamento do sistema, ou seja, não da erro. Os **imports** devem ficar na **main.py** ? ou não isso não tem nada haver?

Esse sistema tem vários arquivos, vários **imports** e muitas linhas, por isso eu quero saber também se isso interfere na performance.

Comment: O `import sqlalchemy` não gera problemas caso feito no **main.py** se você importá-lo primeiro do que o módulo `add_user.py`. Caso você importe primeiro seu módulo para depois importar o pacote será gerado um erro, pois a parte que precisa do pacote `sqlalchemy` será executado antes.

Comment: É recomendado que você sempre importe nos módulos que utilizam o pacote, para que não haja confusão sobre de onde determinada classe ou função vem, além de evitar problemas caso você acabe excluindo a importação do módulo principal, ao julgar não ser mais útil, quando na verdade você precisa para seu outro módulo.

Comment: E se eu precisar do sqlalchemy em muitos módulos ? eu preciso importar e cada um deles ?

Comment: Normalmente não se importa o módulo inteiro, mas sim alguma função ou classe do mesmo. Para um exemplo, eu vou utilizar a biblioteca `tkinter`. Ao invés de importar o pacote por completo, importe no módulo principal a classe `Tk`, em outro módulo X as classes `Button` e `Entry`, em outro módulo Z a classe `Label`, etc. A sintaxe para tal é `from <module | package> import <item>`. Geralmente só se importa o pacote inteiro quando ele é utilizado em apenas um módulo, na linguagem Python — em outras linguagens pode ser diferente a forma de importar — ou quando o pacote não é um muito grande.

Comment: O comportamento não muda porque o módulo carregado uma vez fica em cache https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache

Comment: Eu sou novo no stackoverflow, tanto no inglês quanto no português, mas as pessoas aqui não respondem as perguntas? como eu vou marcar a resposta certa?

Comment: Leia essa questão para entender melhor: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/157404

Comment: Você pode clicar na setinha ao lado do comentário como forma de "like", caso tenha gostado da resposta em forma de comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento do sistema não muda devido ao [module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache), pois uma vez que o módulo — ou pacote — é carregado, ele será gravado no *cache* até o fim da execução do programa, sendo acessível também aos módulos que importarem o módulo contendo a importação do pacote.

Entretanto, você deve tomar muito cuidado com a ordem das importações no seu código. Supondo que a importação do `sqlalchemy` fique no `main.py`, ele deve vir antes da importação do módulo `add_user.py`. Caso o contrário, o código do seu módulo será carregado primeiro e o interpretador irá lançar um `NameError` — devido ao fato do pacote `sqlalchemy` ainda não ter sido importado, para ser usado no seu código.

```
import sqlalchemy
import add_user   # Esse módulo precisa do "sqlalchemy", por isso vem depois.
```

Quanto à performance do programa, muitas importações podem sim gerar problemas. O ideal é importar somente as classes e funções que você precisará, ao invés de importar todo o pacote. Para isso, utilize a sintaxe abaixo:

```
from <pacote> import <item1>, <item2>, ...
```

Ademais, é recomendado que você sempre realize as importações diretamente nos módulos que dependem delas para funcionarem. O motivo disso é evitar possíveis confusões sobre de onde determinada classe ou função vem. Imagine que você está trabalhando em um projeto com dezenas de módulos, e em um deles, você se depara com esse código, logo nas primeiras linhas:

```
db = Database(core.URL)
db.init()

# ...
```

E agora? De onde veio essa classe `Database` ou esse `core`? Mesmo em projetos pequenos e pessoais, você pode acabar se confundindo em algum momento, ainda mais se você largar o projeto por alguns meses — ou quem sabe, anos.

Além disso, quando você não importa o pacote diretamente no módulo que depende dele, seu código fica dependente de seu outro módulo. E isso é **muito ruim**! O melhor a se fazer é sempre criar código **independentes**. Dessa forma, você evita problemas no seu programa, caso a importação seja apagada acidentalmente.

> E como é possível eu acidentalmente apagar uma importação na qual eu preciso?

Imagine que você importe um pacote X somente no seu módulo principal, a fim de utilizar o pacote em ambos os módulos. Se passa algumas semanas, ou meses, e você reescreve o código do módulo principal, substituindo o pacote X pelo pacote Z — por julgar ser melhor. Como não faz mais sentido importar o pacote X já que você não utiliza-o mais no módulo, você decide apagá-lo.

O que acontecerá? Um belíssimo `NameError` será lançado. Porque mesmo que o seu módulo principal não precise mais do pacote X, o seu outro módulo precisa. Por esse viés, mantenha suas importações sempre separadas, dentro de cada módulo que dependa delas.

> E quando eu devo importar por completo um pacote ou módulo?

Como eu disse acima, o ideal é sempre importar "pedaços" do módulo. Mas existem momentos em que não há problema em importar um módulo por completo — ou é até mesmo recomendado, para fins de organização.

Um desses momentos é quando você precisa do nome do módulo para deixar o seu código mais organizado. Um bom exemplo de módulo para se utilizar a importação "normal" é o `math`, pois ele é muito pequeno e deixa o código mais organizado, devido ao fato de se precisar declarar o nome do módulo antes da função e constantes, evitando novamente confusões.

```
result = 4 * pi * pow(radius, 3) / 3
result = 4 * math.pi * math.pow(radius, 3) / 3  # Bem melhor, não acha? :)
```

Comment: Deixar os módulos/pacotes independentes um dos outros se chama desacoplamento e é quase um pré-requisito pra testes unitários